# Get users by custom field and field type

Tags: users, javascript, database

I'm using `Drupal 7`. 
I'm trying to get all users with custom field `field_id`:

```
$users = user_load_multiple(array(), array('field_id' => '123456789'));
var_dump($users);
```

and I got the following error:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.field_id' in 'where clause': SELECT base.uid AS uid, base.name AS name, base.pass AS pass, base.mail AS mail, base.theme AS theme, base.signature AS signature, base.signature_format AS signature_format, base.created AS created, base.access AS access, base.login AS login, base.status AS status, base.timezone AS timezone, base.language AS language, base.picture AS picture, base.init AS init, base.data AS data FROM {users} base WHERE (base.field_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 123456789 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 191 of C:\wamp\www\my_proj\includes\entity.inc).

**My questions:**
1. How can get users by custom field ? 
2. How to query the field type ? (is it text, int, float, etc..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) for that:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->fieldCondition('field_id', 'value', $field_id);
```

There's no native way to query by type of field. To do that you'll need to use the [`EntityFieldQuery::addTag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AaddTag/7) method to add a custom tag to the query, and then use [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) to manually join the `field_config` table into the query before it's run.

Comment: Looks like you and [this guy](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/59775/16495) use similar source for code snippets ;)

Comment: I think he was asking because of `$conditions` on [user_load_multiplel](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_multiple/7), but under close inspection the API says the `$conditions` can only be on the `{users}` table. :)

Comment: @tenken Yeah `$conditions` it's a properties-only thing; it's also deprecated

Comment: @Mołot That would be 'brain' :)

Comment: @Clive I mean to get back the field type as I set it, for example field_id as text and also native types like email.

Comment: @NickF Yep that's what I thought you meant, the answer applies directly to that. You can't natively query on a field's metadata with an `EntityFieldQuery`