# Get only one field from profile

Tags: 7, users, performance

I have a profile field called "myutr" that I need to pass to the browser, for ALL pages, via js

```
drupal_add_js(....)
```

I know that $user does not contain profile fields so to get the value of this field I need to load it via

```
$account = user_load($user);
drupal_add_js($account->myutr); //I know that is not the correct code
```

But in a big site with more and more page views call user_load only for a field is for me a bad perfomance practice. So: is there a possibility to load only this field via drupal standard api ? Or I need to call db_query(....) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article, I've used the method in the past.

http://timonweb.com/working-with-drupal-fields-getting-single-field-values-for-display-and-manipulaton

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: field_view_field() and field_get_items() requires that entity is loaded. I don't want to load user fields only for 1 field (performance). However thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Queries will probably work!

Taken from this answer: [How to get users (entities) for a certain field value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31390/how-to-get-users-entities-for-a-certain-field-value)

Just add in the condition for the current userid.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->fieldCondition('field_birthday', 'value', $birthday);

$result = $query->execute();
$users_ids = array_keys($result['user']);
```

Comment: I don't need to search users for a value, I need to get only 1 field's value for a user that I know (uid). But I don't want to load ALL users fields/data.